# Why can't I find the dba datafile on the server where the database is?

Tags: oracle

This query give the list of the different datafile:

```
SELECT fil.FILE_NAME FROM dba_data_files fil
```

> :D/Oracle.......

this query give me where the database is running

```
SELECT SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','TERMINAL') FROM dual;
```

On the same serveur, I'm searching the datafiles. in :D/. But there is no subfolder Oracle.

I've searched with explorer and with powershell:

```
 Get-ChildItem D:\ -Hidden
```

Why?

Comment: `TERMINAL` refers to where where the client is running, not the server. So are you sure you're actually looking on the right machine? Your connection settings might be a better place to look - though with RAC the listener might not be on the same machine as the data files either.

Comment: Thanks. select sys_context('USERENV','SERVER_HOST') from dual give me the real name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get the server name. replace TERMINAL by SERVER_HOST

```
 select sys_context('USERENV','SERVER_HOST') from dual
```